# access the Ribbon object model outside of a VSTO add-in

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, vsto, ribbonx

I am trying to access the ribbon of Microsoft office word file using C#. and trying to change its visibility inside a background worker. Please help

Comment: Please read [ask] [tour] and [mcve], we sadly cant see your code or whats happening as it stands

Answer (score 1):

By design, this is not possible. An Office Ribbon can only be controlled from code running *in-process* in the host Office application. What's more, the Ribbon definition must be part of the "container" of the code that's should affect the Ribbon.

This was a conscious and desired design decision by Microsoft after the experiences it has with the Ribbon predecessor - the `CommandBars` object model.